# Create fat jar file with android lib

Tags: android, uberjar

I want to build a fat jar include android library(android.content.Context, android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Typeface......) and some .jar dependency. Can I do it on Android Studio or IntelJ Idea??

Comment: gradle shadow plugin... Yes. But why? Where are you running your code that will not have the Android SDK?

Comment: I mean I want to make a .Jar file for importing to other project Android. My .Jar file have construction (Ex : public BankController(Contex context) , and some functions have to include android lib.

Comment: @cricket_007 , I thought I have to : Create Android Project -->Import other .jar file --> Write my constructor, functions that have to import android lib  -->build all of them to fat Jar . But I dont know How can I buill all of them to Fat Jar??Can you help me?

Comment: You don't need a fat jar. You need a regular Android library. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: Yes, I know we can create .aar file, but someone still use eclipse or some tools and .jar is best suitable. I saw someone can build it and all of library is .jar on Maven Repository, but How? how can I do that?

Comment: 1) Have to ask those people. They probably have a BinTray account. 2) Eclipse is deprecated devlopment environment for Android. 3) Those are not fat jars. 4) JitPack works off Github directly. https://jitpack.io/

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 so much, you have good knowledge. But I still want to build a jar file seem like "butterknife" https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife/7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make and export a .jar file that can include android lib and other jar. Example : "butterknife-7.0.0.jar" at mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife/7.0.0

[butterknife-7.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1hMJ.png)